# Persist users with redux-persist and aws-amplify

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, aws-amplify, redux-persist

I'm trying to persist user connection in my React-native app.

I'm using :

```
"aws-amplify": "1.0.2",
"aws-amplify-react-native": "1.0.2",
"aws-appsync": "^1.3.1",
"aws-appsync-react": "^1.1.1",
"react": "16.4.1",
"react-native": "0.55.4",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"redux": "^4.0.0",
"redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
```

This is my current code :

```
// AppSync init
const client = new Client({
  url: AppSync.graphqlEndpoint,
  region: AppSync.region,
  auth:{
    type: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS',
    jwtToken: async () => (await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken(),
      },

  disableOffline: true
})
```

I'm using the default config with redux-perist :

```
const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
}
```

The only thing that I want is to retrieve the jwtToken from the "rehydrated" store (provide by redux-persist) when an user rerun the application.

I found no information about the association of these libraries.

Hope someone could help me.

Comment: Why not store the JWT in AsyncStorage? redux-persist is for persisting your Redux store.

Comment: So you think that it's better to store the JWT in AsynStorage rather than use the redux store ?

Comment: Most definitely, it's a perfect use case if you're only storing a single JWT.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I have succeeded in storing and getting the JWT using AsyncStorage.